# How to use @ViewChildren in Angular2?

Tags: angular

In my home.html:

```
<p #pmessage>msg 1</p>
<p #pmessage>msg 2</p>
<p #pmessage>msg 3</p>
<p #pmessage>msg 4</p>
```

In my home.ts:

```
export class HomePage {
    @ViewChildren('pmessage') pMessages;

    constructor() {
         //using first works, result <p>msg 1</p>
         console.log(this.pMessages.first.nativeElement);
         //using last also works, result <p>msg 4</p>
         console.log(this.pMessages.last.nativeElement);
         //How can I get the two in the middle? i.e <p>msg 2</p> and <p>msg 3</p>
         //this isn't working
         console.log(this.pMessage[1].nativeElement); 
         //this either isn't working
         console.log(this.pMessage.1.nativeElement); 
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You can't access `this.pMessages` in the constructor. It is only set when `ngAfterViewInit()` was called.

Comment: try this:

console.log(this.pMessage.toArray()[1].nativeElement);

Comment: try console.log(this.pMessages._results[1]._elementRef.nativeElement) that worked for me

Answer (score 2):

There is typo in accessing `pMessages`.  The 's' is missing.

```
`console.log(this.pMessages[1].nativeElement);`
```

Also you should access viewChildren in `ngAfterViewInit` or later.  The variable could be `undefined` before that

Comment: Your solution is not working. Please see my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/yuYQz7Mt1KGfzpWV0GrK?p=preview